# Apache2 home directory on Fedora

Tags: fedora, permissions, apache-httpd, selinux

I want to serve docs on my dev server from my home directory. This is a private laptop, so I'm not really concerned with security as far as you are with most servers / web hosting situations.

The `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/myuser/www"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/home/myuser/www">
    AllowOverride all
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/home/myuser/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So far it's ok and I can now view the docs in the `myuser/www` directory at `http://localhost/`.

However, apache can't write to the directory and I'm getting selinux security warnings.

I tried adding my user to the `apache` group, and setting the `myuser/www` directory to `755` permissions, but this didn't work.

How do I allow apache to write to this directory?

EDIT:

After changing the group and permissions on the `/home/myuser/www/` directory, the files display, but the app is complaining that apache cannot write to the tmp directory and it throws an selinux error. The recommended fix in the security message is to execute the following commands, which I've done with no change:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'tmp'
# restorecon -v 'tmp'
```

Comment: I don't see how /tmp/ is related to this. I would just try to test to disable SElinux in order to be sure it is the only problem. And then decide what to do

Comment: The `tmp` part should probably be a separate question. Can you ask that as a new question please, including the full AVC denial?

Answer (score 0):

Do `chgrp apache` on your home directory
(and any files and subdirectories that you want Apache to be able to write to),
and do `chmod g+w` on them. 
This will set directories to 7**7**5 mode, and files to 664.

Comment: @G-Man-- thanks. The issue now is that we're not allowed to write to `tmp`. I did the suggested fix but still getting the error: 
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'tmp'
# restorecon -v 'tmp'

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you did and what happened as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from the `httpd_selinux` man page, available in the `selinux-policy-doc` package:

> If you want  to  allow  httpd  to  read  home  directories,  you  must  turn  on  the
>          httpd_enable_homedirs boolean. Disabled by default.
>
> ```
>   setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
> ```

Your problems with `/tmp` might depend on what exactly you're trying to do. Note that by default, `httpd` on Fedora uses a private namespace for `/tmp` — this might not be what your software wants. What is your application using that for?

Comment: I think it's the `tmp` dir set in the php.ini that's causing the issue. I'd expect that the php installation would have set that path appropriately. What should the correct value for the tmp path be?

Comment: What Fedora release are you on?

Comment: `~  cat /etc/fedora-release` 
Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)

Comment: Hmmm. There was a very old bug about this, but with recent releases including 23, it should just "magically" happen — files written by httpd/php should have a transition to the correct `httpd_php_tmp_t`.